# Exclude post format from navigation

Tags: navigation, post-formats

I would like to exclude the post format "image" from the navigation at the bottom of my single posts.

How would I be able to amend the following code to exclude the "images" post format?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sparkling_post_nav' ) ) :
function sparkling_post_nav() {
    // Don't print empty markup if there's nowhere to navigate.
    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

    if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <nav class="navigation post-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'sparkling' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <?php
                previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> %title', 'Previous post link', 'sparkling' ) );
                next_post_link(     '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>',     _x( '%title <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>', 'Next post link',     'sparkling' ) );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- .navigation -->
    <?php
}
endif;
```

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your function add:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'image' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Actually that just removes the navigation, it doesn't filters the output. To amend the results you would need to filter `get_adjacent_post` is some way.